# Split values in string separated by both comma and a letter

Tags: c++, string, split, arduino

I am currently working with Arduino where I have a string, that for example looks like this:

```
"30,30,20,10,50,50M20"
```

I say for example, because the values can always change. The letter however will always be a 1 word letter. There will always be 7 numbers and 1 letter. The letter will always be in between value 6 and 8.

In that string there are different values and they are separated by both commas and also a letter which makes the solution it a bit more tricky.

If I break the string above I need to store it like this:

> A = 30
>   B = 30
>   C = 20
>   D = 10
>   E = 50
>   F = 50
>   G = M
>   H = 20

These values regularly change (and the length of each value) so the code has to be setup in a way so it separates the values by the `','` and also the letter, in this case `'M'`.

This is what I tried to do myself:

```
char c = Serial.read(); 
FindA = c.indexOf(',');
A = c.substring(0, ind1); 
FindB = c.indexOf(',', ind1+1 );       
B = c.substring(ind1+1, ind2+1);
```

And then somehow implement so it takes out the value before and after the letter (that also needs to be stored).

I have this outcommented too `String recievedMessage += (char)Serial.read();`.

I am developing on an Arduino.

Comment: I'm not familar with arduino but in in C++ `char` is a single byte character primitive type. This type does not have any member functions.

Comment: What is the return type of `Serial.read()`?

Comment: @smac89 Arduino's [`Serial.read()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read) returns `int`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, Op is calling `read` (lowercase) method. Is that the same? Nvm, I see it was a typo

Comment: I have this too (outcommented for now) `String recievedMessage += (char)Serial.read();`

Comment: I think you should put that in your question. Also if that String class is different from `std::string`, you should say that too

Comment: Just so you know, this `String recievedMessage += (char)Serial.read();` is not valid C++. It should either be `String recievedMessage; recievedMessage += (char)Serial.read();` or `String recievedMessage =
 String((char)Serial.read());`

Comment: Will the string always include 7 numbers and a character between the last 2 numbers?

Comment: @gre_gor Yes. There will always be 7 numbers and 1 letter. The letter will always be in between value 6 and 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the strings are sent as lines (with a new line character `\n` at the end).

```cpp
typedef struct {
    int A = 0;
    int B = 0;
    int C = 0;
    int D = 0;
    int E = 0;
    int F = 0;
    char G = 0;
    int H = 0;
} Line;

typedef void (*LineHandler)(Line data);

bool line_parser(char c, LineHandler line_handler) {
    static Line data;
    static int value = 0;
    static byte state = 0;
    bool complete = false;

    // ignore the carriage return character
    if (c == '\r') return complete;

    if (state < 8) {
        if (isdigit(c)) {
            value = value*10 + c-'0';  // add the digit
        }
        else if (c == ',' || c == '\n') {
            // if a comma or end of line is found, save the value
            switch (state) {
                case 0: data.A = value; break;
                case 1: data.B = value; break;
                case 2: data.C = value; break;
                case 3: data.D = value; break;
                case 4: data.E = value; break;
                // the F and G are set when the letter is found
                case 7: data.H = value; break;
            }
            // advance the parsing state and reset the value
            state++;
            value = 0;
        }
        else if (state == 5 && isalpha(c)) { // if parsing the 6th number and a letter is found
            data.F = value; // save the 6th number
            data.G = c; // save the letter
            state += 2; // advance to parsing the 8th value
            value = 0; // reset the value
        }
        else
            state = 10; // unexpected character; stop the parser
    }
    if (c == '\n') {
        if (state == 8) {
            //got complete line
            line_handler(data);
            complete = true;
        }
        else {
            // parsing failed
        }
        // reset the parser
        value = 0;
        state = 0;
    }
    return complete;
}

void handle_line(Line data) {
    // just print out the data
    Serial.println("Line:");
    Serial.print("A = ");
    Serial.println(data.A);
    Serial.print("B = ");
    Serial.println(data.B);
    Serial.print("C = ");
    Serial.println(data.C);
    Serial.print("D = ");
    Serial.println(data.D);
    Serial.print("E = ");
    Serial.println(data.E);
    Serial.print("F = ");
    Serial.println(data.F);
    Serial.print("G = ");
    Serial.println(data.G);
    Serial.print("H = ");
    Serial.println(data.H);
    Serial.println();
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available()) {
        line_parser(Serial.read(), handle_line);
    }
}
```

This parser is non-blocking and is feed character by character and after it receives the whole line, it calls a function that should handle the parsed data.

Sending it:

```
54,125,11045,11,78,4H45
invalid line
11,22,33,44,55,66K88
30,30,20,10,50,50M20
```

should send back:

```
Line:
A = 54
B = 125
C = 11045
D = 11
E = 78
F = 4
G = H
H = 45

Line:
A = 11
B = 22
C = 33
D = 44
E = 55
F = 66
G = K
H = 88

Line:
A = 30
B = 30
C = 20
D = 10
E = 50
F = 50
G = M
H = 20
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a small parser for your string, like:

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cctype>
#include<iterator>
#include<vector>

std::vector<int> values(1);
char separator = ',';

// read every char from the stream and store it in i
for (int i = Serial.read(); i >= 0; i = Serial.read())
{
    // check if i is a digit (and if so, append it to the previous digit)
    if (std::isdigit(i))
    {
        values.back() = values.back() * 10 + std::atoi(i);
    }
    // check if i is a letter [A-Z][a-z]
    else if (std::isalpha(i))
    {
        values.back() = i;
        i = separator;
    }

    // check if i is the separator 
    if (i == separator)
    {
        values.push_back(0);
    }    
}

A = values[0];
B = values[1]
// ...
```

Comment: Hey testing this now. I am written all the code with no syntax errors but i am unsure on how i will store all of the different values in there own string inside ` if (i == separator)`

Comment: A = value[0], B = value[1] something like this?

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez I updated the code. From your questions, it looks like you are not very familiar with C++. I highly suggest reading some basics about modern C++ (C++ 11 or later).

Comment: I will take a look! Yea im very new to c++. Will do

Comment: Trying to download vector on Arduino. Struggeling a bit. Is there another option or is vector the way to go?

Comment: It's c++ so there are plenty of options. You could replace values with an array `int values[8]` but then you have to handle indexing yourself (`values.back()` doesn't work anymore). Another option is this library for arduino https://github.com/maniacbug/StandardCplusplus which let you use std::vector.